# Redirect Loop When Redirecting Single Pages to HTTPS in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect some http pages to https using .htaccess but get a redirect loop every time.

My latest code is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(page1\.php|page2\.php|page3\.php|page4\.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

I have no idea why this is happening; I've tried about four or five different ways from other related questions but I always get a redirect loop.

EDIT:

Also tried:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^devon-designs.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.devon-designs.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
rewritecond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
rewriterule ^whoweare\.php(.*)$ https://www.devon-designs.com/whoweare.php$1 [r=301]
```

But to redirect my page whoweare.php but still get a redirect loop!

EDIT 2: Tried in PHP

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: https://www.devon-designs.com/whoweare.php"); 
?>
```

Still get a redirect loop. Could this be a hosting configuration issue?

Comment: Can you provide full .htaccess here

Comment: Using mod_rewrite is [not the recommended](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) approach. Use [Redirect](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) instead.

Comment: Hi Markus, I've just tried: 

redirect 301 /whoweare.php https://devon-designs.com/whoweare.php

So redirect a single page to https, but nothing happens.

Comment: Hi anubhava, that was my full htaccess file as i commented out everything else (just the www redirect to make things simple). 

One thing I noticed when I use mod_rewrite as per my original post is that it appends the root folder name in my url.

so

http://devon-designs.com/whoweare.php

Becomes:

https://devon-designs.com/devon-designs/whoweare.php

(with a redirect loop) 

So I tried removing the %{HTTP_HOST} part, but then I get a dns lookup error.